# MYSQL Query in a loop

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query but it gives me same value for entire loop. I must get a different value for $ckxf[usercookie] everytime, what am i doing wrong.

```
$queryxyzzy12=("SELECT * FROM visitorcookiesbrowsing ORDER by id ASC");
    $resultxyzzy23=mysql_query($queryxyzzy12) or die(mysql_error());

    //var_dump($ckxf);
    while($ckxf = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultxyzzy23)){
    $querycrtx=("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE userkey='$ckxf[usercookie]' ORDER by datebegan  DESC");
    $resultcrtx=mysql_query($querycrtx) or die(mysql_error());
    $numcrtx=mysql_numrows($resultcrtx);
    $ixxy=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You know that you can do this in only one query :

```
SELECT * FROM visitorcookiebrowsing v 
LEFT JOIN cart c on c.userkey=v.usercookie 
ORDER by v.id ASC, c.datebegan  DESC
```

Learn the power of SQL:)

Comment: It will also execute a lot faster ;-?